# Libxml - change encoding to windows-1252

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, libxml2

Using Libxml, how can I change encoding format to windows-1252? It doesn't seem to have this option in the encoding constants.

Did I have to use Iconv or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I've decided to use builder..